# No carga el componente en react. error en http://localhost:3000/ muestra el mensaje en la pagina Cannot GET / al tratar de cargar componente React

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, reactjs

### **file:server.js**

```
const express = require('express');

    const express = require('express');
const app = express();

    const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(3000, function () {

    app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('server on port 3000');

        console.log('server on port 3000');
});

    });
```

---

**file: index.jsx**

import React,{Component} from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom';

`class Prueba extends  Component{
     render(){
     <h1>Plantilla React</h1>
   }}


     render(< Prueba/>,document.getElementById('app'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agregue el **return**,  inclui la siguiente linea

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

Reinicie el ordenador,compile de nuevo por **npm install react react-dom --save**, corri de nuevo el server y todo funciona perfecto!

Comment: **Te dejo un tip por experiencia:** cuando trabajas con express, aunque tengas un HRM (hot reload module) para refrescar automáticamente tu código o hagas CTRL + F5 para refrescar tu navegador, a veces hace falta pararlo y rearrancarlo para que vuelva a coger todos los cambios.

Answer (score 3):

**Primer problema**

En ningún momento estás mapeando una ruta para renderizar el HTML. Deberías mapear toda petición `GET` para renderizar el index. Para eso usa el wilcard *all* (*):

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
const root = <>; // directorio en donde está el index
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile('index.html', { root }));
app.liste(3000);
```

**Segundo problema**

El método `render` debe retornar un elemento; tú no estás retornando nada:

```
render() {
  return (
    <h1>Hola mundo</h1>
  );
}
```

Comment: Al usar return, se soluciona el mensaje del error, **Cannot GET**
al aplicar su respuesta,modificando:  
*const root =__filename+'/public/index.html'; *


**Queda en blanco el browser sin errores... aún no se ve el mensaje de Plantilla React**

Comment: @Developer, asegurate de que tu index.html tenga un elemento con id = "app". Lo incluí en mi respuesta

Comment: Si revise y lo tiene ok, el problema ahora es el siguiente: ** Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000**

Comment: Ya solucione el *Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000*, pero sigue apareciendo en blanco el browser, sin enviar el mensaje

Comment: **SOLUCIONADO:** compile de nuevo, npm react-dom y todo funciona perfecto!

Answer (score 0):

El problema no está en React, sino en express. No has definido una ruta para que atienda los request que llegan a la raíz.

Aqui modifique tu archivo para incluir una función que enviará el archivo index.html a **todos** los request que reciba.

**file: server.js**

```
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express(); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
   res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('server on port 3000');
});
```

Suponiendo que existe un archivo **index.html** al mismo nivel que server:

```
<div id="app"> <!-- la plantilla react debería aparecer aqui --> </div>
```

Asegúrate de que tu index.html tenga un elemento con id="app", dado que ahí es donde le estás indicando a react que realice el Render, con el `document.getElementById('app')`